# Как избавится от утечки памяти

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Собственно код (пример тестовый, но реальную аналогичную ситуацию моделирует на 100%):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    test meml;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        meml = new test();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        meml.Run();
    } 
}
public class test
{
    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) RunMemoryLeak();
    }
    private void RunMemoryLeak()
    {
        unsafe
        {
            var ImgPointer = (void*)new Bitmap(700, 700).GetHbitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно при нажатии на кнопку приложение "съедает" ~ 380мб (один Bitmap(700, 700) это ~ 1,9мб если умножить на 200 как раз выйдет объём откушаной памяти) Сборщик мусора данную память не освобождает. Предупреждения GC о большом объёме выделенной памяти в неуправляемом блоке (GC.AddMemoryPressure) не спасают. Зануление указателя так же. Зануление объекта meml аналогично.

Моих знаний .Net'a не хватает, чтобы объяснить данную ситуацию. Кто знает, что тут происходит? Где выделяется память и почему она не освобождается? И как данный код исправить/дополнить чтобы многократный его вызов не приводил к OutOfMemoryException

PS: 15-ая студия, 10-ая винда, 4-ый фреймворк

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GetHBitmap создает из вашего Bitmap старый добрый неуправляемый BITMAP из GDI, который никак не контролируется ни .NET, ни сборщиком мусора. Его нужно освобождать вручную.

Об освобождении памяти из-под результата вызова GetHBitmap прямо сказано в [MSDN по этому методу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx), с примером:

> Пользователь несет ответственность за вызов метода DeleteObject объекта GDI для высвобождения памяти, использованной точечным рисунком GDI

```
private void DemonstrateGetHbitmap()
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap("Picture.jpg");
    IntPtr hBitmap = bm.GetHbitmap();

    // Do something with hBitmap.
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```